# Olingo 2.0.6 JPA Extension: EdmComplexTypeImplProv cannot be cast to EdmSimpleType

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, odata, olingo

When using the JPA Extension to scan an entity that includes @Embedded objects the $metadata is created correctly with ComplexTypes. However, when retrieving the entity I receive a ClassCastException:

> org.apache.olingo.odata2.core.edm.provider.EdmComplexTypeImplProv
>   cannot be cast to org.apache.olingo.odata2.api.edm.EdmSimpleType
>
> Class:
>   org.apache.olingo.odata2.jpa.processor.core.access.data.JPAEntityParse

Here is the entity code I'm using:

```
@Entity
public class BORROWER {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Embedded
    protected BORROWER_DETAIL borrower_DETAIL;



    @Embedded
    protected NAME name;


    @ManyToOne
    protected DEAL deal;


    //Mark transient to force orika to skip
    @Transient
    public DEAL getDeal() {
        return deal;
    }

    public void setDeal(DEAL deal) {
        this.deal = deal;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the borrower_DETAIL property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *
     *     
     */
    public BORROWER_DETAIL getBORROWER_DETAIL() {
        return borrower_DETAIL;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the borrower_DETAIL property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *
     *     
     */
    public void setBORROWER_DETAIL(BORROWER_DETAIL value) {
        this.borrower_DETAIL = value;
    }

    public NAME getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(NAME name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing the comment regarding getter/setters being the source of the issue on this bug ticket (also I borrowed parts of the write up for the question):

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OLINGO-948

I updated the getter and setter method signatures for borrower_DETAIL, and I'm no longer getting the error. Here is the updated entity code that is working for me:

```
@Entity
public class BORROWER {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Embedded
    protected BORROWER_DETAIL borrower_DETAIL;



    @Embedded
    protected NAME name;


    @ManyToOne
    protected DEAL deal;


    //Mark transient to force orika to skip
    @Transient
    public DEAL getDeal() {
        return deal;
    }

    public void setDeal(DEAL deal) {
        this.deal = deal;
    }

    public BORROWER_DETAIL getBorrower_DETAIL() {
        return borrower_DETAIL;
    }

    public void setBorrower_DETAIL(BORROWER_DETAIL borrower_DETAIL) {
        this.borrower_DETAIL = borrower_DETAIL;
    }

    public NAME getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(NAME name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```